# Maze generator & animator in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, image, animation

This is a follow up to this code and I still did not get the feedback on the drawing functions

[Maze generator in Python- Gif animator-Custom colors/sizes](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/227363/maze-generator-in-python-gif-animator-custom-colors-sizes)

The code generates custom color and size mazes with optional generation of either a single full maze image or an animated GIF for the maze being created. 6 algorithms were implemented so far which are presented with examples below and more algorithms will be added to this code, awaiting your suggestions for improvements and feedback for the overall code specially the drawing functions.

Code works perfectly fine however my main concern is how to improve the drawing functions `_make_grid_image()`, `produce_maze_image()` and `produce_maze_visualization()` in terms of drawing accuracy, I want the paint-re paint procedure to be accurate using any given line width or size given that unless I change variables inside the body of the functions each time I change the width/size of the maze, I would get a pixelated image(and this is due to the absence of some method adjusting the drawing coordinates(and I do this manually each time I decide to change line width or the general size of the maze generated) I want something that automates the adjustment each to prevent a manual adjustment or getting pixelated images without changing the structure of the code. If you have any questions about the code, feel free to ask and I included some GIFs and description for the algorithms used so far. Take your time examining the code and I apologize if it's a bit long I'm constantly trying to eliminate repetition/redundancy as well as possible.

***Algorithms implemented so far:***

**1. Binary Tree Algorithm Description:**

Binary Tree Maze Generator is one of the very rareful algorithms with the ability to generate a perfect maze without keeping any state at all: it is an exact memoryless Maze generation algorithm with no limit to the size of Maze you can create. It can build the entire maze by looking at each cell independently. This is the most straightforward and fastest algorithm possible.

**Maze generated examples (25 % average dead ends):**

[image: Binary Tree - 50 x 50 Black & white]
[image: Binary Tree - 50 x 50 Blue & Yellow]
[image: Binary Tree - 50 x 50]

**2. Sidewinder Algorithm Description:**

Sidewinder Maze Generator is very similar to the Binary Tree algorithm, and only slightly more complicated. Furthermore, the Sidewinder algorithm only needs to consider the current row, and therefore can be used to generate infinitely large mazes (like the Binary Tree).While binary tree mazes have two of its four sides being one long passage, Sidewinder mazes have just one long passage.

**Maze generated examples: (28% average dead ends)**

[image: Sidewinder - 50 x 50 Black and White]
[image: Sidewinder = 50 x 50 Black and Gold]
[image: Sidewinder 50 x 50]

**3.Aldous Broder Algorithm Description:**

The Aldous-Broder algorithm is an algorithm for generating uniform spanning trees of a graph. Uniform Spanning Tree means "a maze generated in such a way that it was randomly selected from a list of every possible maze to be generated.

**Maze generated examples: (29% average dead ends)**

[image: Aldous Broder - 50 x 50 Black and White]
[image: Aldous Broder - 50 x 50 Dark Green and Turquoise]
[image: Aldous Broder - 50 x 50]

**4.Wilson Algorithm Description:**

Wilson’s algorithm uses loop-erased random walks to generate a uniform spanning tree — an unbiased sample of all possible spanning trees. Most other maze generation algorithms do not have this beautiful property (similar to Aldous Broder but more efficient)

**Maze generated examples: (30% average dead ends)**

[image: Wilson - 50 x 50 Black and White]
[image: Wilson - 50 x 50 Dark Blue and Pink]
[image: Wilson - 50 x 50]

**5.Recursive Backtracker Algorithm Description:**

The Recursive Backtracker Algorithm is probably the most widely used algorithm for maze generation. It has an implementation that many programmers can relate with (Recursive Backtracking).

*** Note: for efficiency, no recursion was used in the implementation, only backtracking.

**Maze generated examples: (10% average dead ends)**

[image: Recursive Backtracker - 50 x 50 Black and White]
[image: Recursive Backtracker - 50 x 50 Purple and white]
[image: Recursive Backtracker - 50 x 50]

**6.Hunt And Kill Algorithm Description:**

Works similarly to recursive backtracking algorithm, without the backtracking part.

**Maze generated examples: (10% average dead ends)**

[image: Hunt And Kill - 50 x 50 Black and White]
[image: Hunt And Kill - 50 x 50 Red and Cyan]
[image: Hunt And Kill - 50 x 50]

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
from PIL import Image, ImageDraw
from time import perf_counter
import random
import os
import glob
import imageio
import shutil


class Cell:
    """Create grid cell."""
    def __init__(self, row_index, column_index, rows, columns):
        """
        Initiate grid cell.
        row_index: cell row index.
        column_index: cell column index.
        rows: number of rows in grid.
        columns: number of columns in grid.
        """
        if row_index >= rows or row_index < 0:
            raise ValueError(f'Expected a row index in range(0, {rows}) exclusive, got {row_index}')
        if column_index >= columns or column_index < 0:
            raise ValueError(f'Expected a column index in range(0, {columns} exclusive, got {column_index}')
        self.row = row_index
        self.column = column_index
        self.rows = rows
        self.columns = columns
        self.linked_cells = []

    def neighbors(self, grid):
        """Return North, South, East, West neighbor cells."""
        neighbors = []
        north = self.row - 1, self.column
        if north[0] < 0:
            north = 0
            neighbors.append(0)
        if north:
            neighbors.append(grid[north[0]][north[1]])
        south = self.row + 1, self.column
        if south[0] >= self.rows:
            south = 0
            neighbors.append(0)
        if south:
            neighbors.append(grid[south[0]][south[1]])
        east = self.row, self.column + 1
        if east[1] >= self.columns:
            east = 0
            neighbors.append(0)
        if east:
            neighbors.append(grid[east[0]][east[1]])
        west = self.row, self.column - 1
        if west[1] < 0:
            west = 0
            neighbors.append(0)
        if west:
            neighbors.append(grid[west[0]][west[1]])
        return neighbors

    def link(self, other, grid):
        """Link 2 unconnected cells."""
        if self in other.linked_cells or other in self.linked_cells:
            raise ValueError(f'{self} and {other} are already connected.')
        if self.columns != other.columns or self.rows != other.rows:
            raise ValueError('Cannot connect cells in different grids.')
        if self not in other.neighbors(grid) or other not in self.neighbors(grid):
            raise ValueError(f'{self} and {other} are not neighbors and cannot be connected.')
        if not isinstance(other, Cell):
            raise TypeError(f'Cannot link Cell to {type(other)}.')
        self.linked_cells.append(other)
        other.linked_cells.append(self)

    def unlink(self, other):
        """Unlink 2 connected cells."""
        if self not in other.linked_cells or other not in self.linked_cells:
            raise ValueError(f'{self} and {other} are not connected.')
        self.linked_cells.remove(other)
        other.linked_cells.remove(self)

    def coordinates(self):
        """Return cell (row, column)."""
        return self.row, self.column

    def is_linked(self, other):
        """Return True if 2 cells are linked."""
        return other in self.linked_cells

    def __str__(self):
        """Cell display."""
        return f'Cell{self.coordinates()}'

    def __repr__(self):
        """Cell representation."""
        return f'Cell{self.coordinates()}'


class Maze:
    """
    Generate a maze using different algorithms:
    - Binary Tree Algorithm.
    - Sidewinder Algorithm.
    - Aldous-Broder Algorithm.
    - Wilson Algorithm.
    - Hunt And Kill Algorithm.
    - Recursive Backtracker Algorithm.
    """
    def __init__(self, rows, columns, width, height, line_width=5, line_color='black', background_color='white'):
        """
        Initiate maze variables:
        rows: number of rows in initial grid.
        columns: number of columns in initial grid.
        width: width of the frame(s).
        height: height of the frame(s).
        line_width: width of grid/maze lines.
        line_color: color of grid/maze lines.
        background_color: color of the grid/maze background (cells/path)
        """
        if width % columns != 0:
            raise ValueError(f'Width: {width} not divisible by number of columns: {columns}.')
        if height % rows != 0:
            raise ValueError(f'Height: {height} not divisible by number of {rows}.')
        self.rows = rows
        self.columns = columns
        self.width = width
        self.height = height
        self.line_width = line_width
        self.line_color = line_color
        self.background_color = background_color
        self.cell_width = width // columns
        self.cell_height = height // rows
        self.drawing_constant = line_width // 2
        self.path = '/Users/emadboctor/Desktop/New code folder September 7 2019/Mazes for programmers/Maze test/'
        # self.path = input('Enter path to folder to save maze creation GIF: ').rstrip()
        self.configurations = {
            'b': self._binary_tree_configuration(),
            's': self._side_winder_configuration(),
            'ab': self._aldous_broder_configuration(),
            'w': self._wilson_configuration(),
            'hk': self._hunt_and_kill_configuration(),
            'rb': self._recursive_back_tracker_configuration()
        }
        self.algorithm_names = {'b': 'BINARY TREE', 's': 'SIDEWINDER', 'ab': 'ALDOUS BRODER', 'w': 'WILSON',
                                'hk': 'HUNT AND KILL', 'rb': 'RECURSIVE BACKTRACKER'}

    def _make_grid_image(self):
        """Initiate maze initial grid image."""
        grid = Image.new('RGB', (self.width, self.height), self.background_color)
        for x in range(0, self.width, self.cell_width):
            x0, y0, x1, y1 = x, 0, x, self.height
            column = (x0, y0), (x1, y1)
            ImageDraw.Draw(grid).line(column, self.line_color, self.line_width)
        for y in range(0, self.height, self.cell_height):
            x0, y0, x1, y1 = 0, y, self.width, y
            row = (x0, y0), (x1, y1)
            ImageDraw.Draw(grid).line(row, self.line_color, self.line_width)
        x_end = (0, self.height - self.drawing_constant),\
                (self.width - self.drawing_constant, self.height - self.drawing_constant)
        y_end = (self.width - self.drawing_constant, 0), (self.width - self.drawing_constant, self.height)
        ImageDraw.Draw(grid).line(x_end, self.line_color, self.line_width)
        ImageDraw.Draw(grid).line(y_end, self.line_color, self.line_width)
        return grid

    def _create_maze_cells(self):
        """Return maze cells."""
        return [[Cell(row, column, self.rows, self.columns) for column in range(self.columns)]
                for row in range(self.rows)]

    def _get_dead_ends(self, maze):
        """
        maze: A 2D list containing finished maze configuration.
        Return dead end cells in current maze configuration.
        """
        return {cell for row in maze for cell in row if len(cell.linked_cells) == 1 and
                str(cell) != str(maze[-1][-1])}

    def _binary_tree_configuration(self):
        """Return binary tree maze configuration."""
        maze_cells = self._create_maze_cells()
        modified_cells = []
        for row in range(self.rows):
            for column in range(self.columns):
                current_cell = maze_cells[row][column]
                north, south, east, west = current_cell.neighbors(maze_cells)
                to_link = random.choice('nw')
                if not north and not west:
                    continue
                if to_link == 'n' and north:
                    current_cell.link(north, maze_cells)
                    modified_cells.append((current_cell, north))
                if to_link == 'w' and west:
                    current_cell.link(west, maze_cells)
                    modified_cells.append((current_cell, west))
                if to_link == 'n' and not north:
                    current_cell.link(west, maze_cells)
                    modified_cells.append((current_cell, west))
                if to_link == 'w' and not west:
                    current_cell.link(north, maze_cells)
                    modified_cells.append((current_cell, north))
        dead_ends = self._get_dead_ends(maze_cells)
        return modified_cells, dead_ends

    def _side_winder_configuration(self):
        """Return sidewinder algorithm maze configuration."""
        maze_cells = self._create_maze_cells()
        checked_cells = []
        modified_cells = []
        for row in range(self.rows):
            for column in range(self.columns):
                current_cell = maze_cells[row][column]
                north, south, east, west = current_cell.neighbors(maze_cells)
                if row == 0 and east:
                    east_cell = maze_cells[row][column + 1]
                    current_cell.link(east_cell, maze_cells)
                    modified_cells.append((current_cell, east_cell))
                if row != 0:
                    checked_cells.append(current_cell)
                    to_link = random.choice('ne')
                    if to_link == 'e' and east:
                        east_cell = maze_cells[row][column + 1]
                        current_cell.link(east_cell, maze_cells)
                        modified_cells.append((current_cell, east_cell))
                    if to_link == 'n' or (to_link == 'e' and not east):
                        random_cell = random.choice(checked_cells)
                        checked_cells.clear()
                        random_cell_coordinates = random_cell.coordinates()
                        random_cell_north_neighbor = maze_cells[random_cell_coordinates[0] - 1][
                            random_cell_coordinates[1]]
                        random_cell.link(random_cell_north_neighbor, maze_cells)
                        modified_cells.append((random_cell, random_cell_north_neighbor))
        dead_ends = self._get_dead_ends(maze_cells)
        return modified_cells, dead_ends

    def _aldous_broder_configuration(self):
        """Return Aldous Broder algorithm maze configuration."""
        maze_cells = self._create_maze_cells()
        modified_cells = []
        starting_cell = maze_cells[random.choice(range(self.rows))][random.choice(range(self.columns))]
        visited = set()
        run = [starting_cell]
        while len(visited) < self.rows * self.columns:
            current_cell = run[-1]
            visited.add(current_cell)
            random_neighbor = random.choice([
             neighbor for neighbor in current_cell.neighbors(maze_cells) if neighbor])
            if random_neighbor not in visited:
                visited.add(random_neighbor)
                run.append(random_neighbor)
                current_cell.link(random_neighbor, maze_cells)
                modified_cells.append((current_cell, random_neighbor))
            if random_neighbor in visited:
                run.clear()
                run.append(random_neighbor)
        dead_ends = self._get_dead_ends(maze_cells)
        return modified_cells, dead_ends

    def _wilson_configuration(self):
        """Return Wilson algorithm maze configuration."""
        maze_cells = self._create_maze_cells()
        unvisited = {cell for row in maze_cells for cell in row}
        starting_cell = random.choice(list(unvisited))
        unvisited.remove(starting_cell)
        visited = {starting_cell}
        path = [random.choice(list(unvisited))]
        unvisited.remove(path[-1])
        modified_cells = []
        while unvisited:
            current_cell = path[-1]
            new_cell = random.choice([neighbor for neighbor in current_cell.neighbors(maze_cells) if neighbor])
            if new_cell in path and new_cell not in visited:
                to_erase_from = path.index(new_cell)
                del path[to_erase_from + 1:]
            if new_cell in visited:
                for cell in path:
                    visited.add(cell)
                    if cell in unvisited:
                        unvisited.remove(cell)
                path.append(new_cell)
                for index in range(len(path) - 1):
                    path[index].link(path[index + 1], maze_cells)
                    modified_cells.append((path[index], path[index + 1]))
                path.clear()
                if unvisited:
                    path.append(random.choice(list(unvisited)))
            if new_cell not in path and new_cell not in visited:
                path.append(new_cell)
        dead_ends = self._get_dead_ends(maze_cells)
        return modified_cells, dead_ends

    def _hunt_and_kill_configuration(self):
        """Return hunt and kill algorithm maze configuration."""
        maze_cells = self._create_maze_cells()
        unvisited = [cell for row in maze_cells for cell in row]
        starting_cell = random.choice(list(unvisited))
        visited = [starting_cell]
        unvisited.remove(starting_cell)
        run = [starting_cell]
        modified_cells = []
        while unvisited:
            current_cell = run[-1]
            valid_neighbors = [neighbor for neighbor in current_cell.neighbors(maze_cells) if neighbor in unvisited]
            if valid_neighbors:
                next_cell = random.choice(valid_neighbors)
                current_cell.link(next_cell, maze_cells)
                modified_cells.append((current_cell, next_cell))
                visited.append(next_cell)
                unvisited.remove(next_cell)
                run.append(next_cell)
            if not valid_neighbors:
                for cell in unvisited:
                    valid_neighbors = [neighbor for neighbor in cell.neighbors(maze_cells) if neighbor in visited]
                    if valid_neighbors:
                        choice = random.choice(valid_neighbors)
                        cell.link(choice, maze_cells)
                        modified_cells.append((cell, choice))
                        unvisited.remove(cell)
                        visited.append(cell)
                        run.append(cell)
                        break
        dead_ends = self._get_dead_ends(maze_cells)
        return modified_cells, dead_ends

    def _recursive_back_tracker_configuration(self):
        """Return recursive backtracker maze configuration."""
        maze_cells = self._create_maze_cells()
        unvisited = [cell for row in maze_cells for cell in row]
        starting_cell = random.choice(unvisited)
        unvisited.remove(starting_cell)
        run = [starting_cell]
        modified = []
        while run:
            current_cell = run[-1]
            valid_neighbors = [neighbor for neighbor in current_cell.neighbors(maze_cells) if neighbor in unvisited]
            if valid_neighbors:
                next_cell = random.choice(valid_neighbors)
                current_cell.link(next_cell, maze_cells)
                modified.append((current_cell, next_cell))
                unvisited.remove(next_cell)
                run.append(next_cell)
            if not valid_neighbors:
                run.pop()
        dead_ends = self._get_dead_ends(maze_cells)
        return modified, dead_ends

    def produce_maze_image(self, configuration):
        """
        configuration: a string representing the algorithm:
        'b': Binary Tree Algorithm.
        's': Sidewinder Algorithm.
        'ab': Aldous Broder Algorithm.
        'w': Wilson Algorithm.
        'hk': Hunt And Kill Algorithm.
        'rb': Recursive Backtracker Algorithm.
        Return maze image according to specified configuration.
        """
        if configuration not in self.configurations:
            raise ValueError(f'Invalid configuration {configuration}')
        cells, dead_ends = self.configurations[configuration]
        maze = self._make_grid_image()
        linked_cells = {cell.coordinates(): [linked.coordinates() for linked in cell.linked_cells]
                        for row in cells for cell in row}
        for row in range(self.rows):
            for column in range(self.columns):
                current_cell_coordinates = (row, column)
                if (row, column + 1) in linked_cells[current_cell_coordinates]:
                    x0 = (column + 1) * self.cell_width
                    y0 = (row * self.cell_height) + (self.line_width - 2)
                    x1 = x0
                    y1 = y0 + self.cell_height - (self.line_width + 1)
                    wall = (x0, y0), (x1, y1)
                    ImageDraw.Draw(maze).line(wall, self.background_color, self.line_width)
                if (row + 1, column) in linked_cells[current_cell_coordinates]:
                    x0 = column * self.cell_width + self.line_width - 2
                    y0 = (row + 1) * self.cell_height
                    x1 = x0 + self.cell_width - (self.line_width + 1)
                    y1 = y0
                    wall = (x0, y0), (x1, y1)
                    ImageDraw.Draw(maze).line(wall, self.background_color, self.line_width)
        x_end = (0, self.height - self.drawing_constant),\
                (self.width - self.drawing_constant, self.height - self.drawing_constant)
        y_end = (self.width - self.drawing_constant, 0), (self.width - self.drawing_constant, self.height)
        ImageDraw.Draw(maze).line(x_end, self.line_color, self.line_width)
        ImageDraw.Draw(maze).line(y_end, self.line_color, self.line_width)
        number_of_dead_ends = len(dead_ends)
        total_cells = self.rows * self.columns
        dead_end_percentage = 100 * (number_of_dead_ends / total_cells)
        print(f'{round(dead_end_percentage, 2)}% dead ends: {number_of_dead_ends} out of {total_cells} cells.')
        return maze

    def produce_maze_visualization(self, frame_speed, configuration):
        """
        ** NOTE: Works on Unix systems only.
        Create a GIF for maze being created by respective specified configuration.
        frame_speed: speed in ms.
        configuration: a string representing the algorithm:
        'b': Binary Tree Algorithm.
        's': Sidewinder Algorithm.
        'ab': Aldous Broder Algorithm.
        'w': Wilson Algorithm.
        'hk': Hunt And Kill Algorithm.
        'rb': Recursive Backtracker Algorithm.
        """
        if configuration not in self.configurations:
            raise ValueError(f'Invalid configuration {configuration}')
        print('GIF creation started ...')
        os.chdir(self.path)
        maze_image = self._make_grid_image()
        cells, dead_ends = self.configurations[configuration]
        count = 0
        for cell1, cell2 in cells:
            cell1_coordinates = cell1.coordinates()
            cell2_coordinates = cell2.coordinates()
            if cell1_coordinates[0] == cell2_coordinates[0]:
                column = min(cell1_coordinates[1], cell2_coordinates[1])
                x0 = (column + 1) * self.cell_width
                row = cell1_coordinates[0]
                y0 = (row * self.cell_height) + (self.line_width - 2)
                x1 = x0
                y1 = y0 + self.cell_height - (self.line_width + 1)
                wall = (x0, y0), (x1, y1)
                ImageDraw.Draw(maze_image).line(wall, self.background_color, self.line_width)
                y_end = (self.width - self.drawing_constant, 0), (self.width - self.drawing_constant, self.height)
                ImageDraw.Draw(maze_image).line(y_end, self.line_color, self.line_width)
                maze_image.save(self.path + str(count) + '.png', 'png')
                count += 1
            # Remove horizontal walls
            if cell1_coordinates[1] == cell2_coordinates[1]:
                column = cell1_coordinates[1]
                x0 = column * self.cell_width + self.line_width - 2
                row = min(cell1_coordinates[0], cell2_coordinates[0])
                y0 = (row + 1) * self.cell_height
                x1 = x0 + self.cell_width - (self.line_width + 1)
                y1 = y0
                wall = (x0, y0), (x1, y1)
                ImageDraw.Draw(maze_image).line(wall, self.background_color, self.line_width)
                x_end = (0, self.height - self.drawing_constant), \
                        (self.width - self.drawing_constant, self.height - self.drawing_constant)
                ImageDraw.Draw(maze_image).line(x_end, self.line_color, self.line_width)
                maze_image.save(self.path + str(count) + '.png', 'png')
                count += 1
        maze_name = ' '.join(
            [self.algorithm_names[configuration], str(self.rows), 'x', str(self.columns), self.background_color,
             'x', self.line_color, 'maze', str(random.randint(10 ** 6, 10 ** 8))]
        )
        os.mkdir(maze_name)
        for file in os.listdir(self.path):
            if file.endswith('.png'):
                shutil.move(file, maze_name)
        os.chdir(maze_name)
        frames = glob.glob('*.png')
        frames.sort(key=lambda x: int(x.split('.')[0]))
        frames = [imageio.imread(frame) for frame in frames]
        imageio.mimsave(self.path + str(maze_name) + '.gif', frames, 'GIF', duration=frame_speed)
        print(f'Creation of {self.algorithm_names[configuration]} {count} frames GIF successful.')
        number_of_dead_ends = len(dead_ends)
        total_cells = self.rows * self.columns
        dead_end_percentage = (number_of_dead_ends / total_cells) * 100
        print(f'{round(dead_end_percentage, 2)}% dead ends: {number_of_dead_ends} out of {total_cells} cells.')


if __name__ == '__main__':
    start_time = perf_counter()
    the_test1 = Maze(50, 100, 1000, 500)
    the_test1.produce_maze_image('rb').show()
    end_time = perf_counter()
    print(f'Time: {end_time - start_time} seconds.')
```

Answer (score 14):

This is a tip I make a lot, but if you have a collection that's simply tracking "membership", and you don't care about order, you should consider using a Set over a List.

I think this is the case for `cell.linked_cells`. The only thing you ever do with `cell.linked_cells` is do `in` membership tests, and add and remove from it.

Make the following changes:

- Initialize it as `self.linked_cells = set()` (Python doesn't have an empty set literal unfortunately)
- Change all `append`s to `add`s, and leave the `remove`s as-is.

This has the potential for speed gains. After these changes, `in` and `remove` will no longer linear; they'll now run in effectively constant time.

---

`is_linked` doesn't appear to ever be used.

---

Conditions like `if row_index >= rows or row_index < 0:` can make use of Python's "comparison chaining":

```
if not 0 <= row_index < rows:
```

It depends on if you think the negation hurts readability or not.

---

I think in `neighbors` you should make the fact that `north` and similar variables are tuples more obvious.

```
north = (self.row - 1, self.column)
```

I think the explicitness of the parenthesis makes it clearer.

And I find it confusing how you're reassigning `north` and other such variables to `0`. You're using `north`, for example, to represent both the tuple of coordinates, *and* as a flag to indicate whether or not the associated condition was True. You also appear to be using `0` to mean `False`. This isn't C! Be explicit about what your intentions are.

My issue with the variables being used like this is, for example, the *type* of `north` will depend on whether or not `north[0] < 0` is `True`. Having a variable conditionally have one type or another is asking for trouble when those types don't share a usable superclass. What if you forget that the type can change and add a line like

```
some_var = north[0] - south[0]
```

(Dumb example, I don't know why you'd need to do this). Now, this will cause exceptions at runtime dependent on if the previous condition was `True` or not. Or say you were wanting to print out `north[0]` for debugging purposes. Now an unrelated error is being thrown, and the information you wanted to see was overwritten by `north = 0`.

To remedy this, I'd:

- Create a *separate* flag variable to track whether or not `north[0] < 0` was True so `north` isn't being used for two separate, unrelated purposes. You could also probably refactor it a bit and make use of an `else` to get rid of the need for a flag altogether. That may add some nesting though.
- Use `False` instead of `0` so it's clear what the intent is.

---

`link` is fairly large even though it isn't doing much. The majority of the method is pre-condition checks to make sure the data is correct, and I think that's muddying the purpose of the method a bit.

I'd split that up:

```
def _link_precondition_check(self, other, grid):
    if self in other.linked_cells or other in self.linked_cells:
        raise ValueError(f'{self} and {other} are already connected.')
    if self.columns != other.columns or self.rows != other.rows:
        raise ValueError('Cannot connect cells in different grids.')
    if self not in other.neighbors(grid) or other not in self.neighbors(grid):
        raise ValueError(f'{self} and {other} are not neighbors and cannot be connected.')
    if not isinstance(other, Cell):
        raise TypeError(f'Cannot link Cell to {type(other)}.')

def link(self, other, grid):
    """Link 2 unconnected cells."""
    self._link_precondition_check(other, grid)

    self.linked_cells.append(other)
    other.linked_cells.append(self)
```

I'll also point out, you're doing a type check at the end there. Whether or not this is necessary is debatable, but if you do want to have type safety, I would make use of [Type Hints](https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html). Yes, Python does have support for weak static typing! I've been making *extensive* use of them lately, and they've helped me avoid dumb mistakes.

You could make the following changes:

```
from __future__ import annotations  # Needed until later versions so classes can reference themselves in type checks
from typing import List

# A grid is a List of List of Cells
def _link_precondition_check(self, other: Cell, grid: List[List[Cell]]):
    . . .

def link(self, other: Cell, grid: List[List[Cell]]):
    . . .
```

I'll note, you can also make type aliases so you don't need to write `List[List[Cell]]` over and over:

```
Grid = List[List[Cell]]
```

Unfortunately, I can't see a good way of declaring this anywhere since it needs to be inside of `Cell` (so that `Cell` exists otherwise `List[List[Cell]]` won't make sense), but can't be declared as a class attribute. Oddly enough, I've never run into this limitation before.

Now you don't need `instanceof` type checks because a good IDE will catch mistakes before the code even runs!

I'd recommend playing around with type hints though. They can help the IDE give you better auto-complete suggestions (since it'll have a better idea of what types it's dealing with), and will allow it to catch you mistakes like it would if Python was statically typed (although it isn't as competent as a good compiler for a statically-typed languages unfortunately).

---

---

I'd keep going, but I gotta get to work here. Good luck!

Comment: Thank you for taking the time, to go through this.