# Maze image solver and animator in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, image, animation, breadth-first-search

This maze solver is a continuation to the maze generator I posted here recently [Maze generator & animator in Python](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/227660/maze-generator-animator-in-python)

This code takes an image containing a 2-color maze as input and solves the maze and produces an image of the solution or an animated GIF. The algorithm implemented so far is breadth-first search(BFS) and I'm intending to post a follow up when other algorithms (A*, Dijkstra ...) are implemented.

---

**It currently has the following features:**

- **Automatic marking** of start and end(Top left to bottom right) by passing `'a'` to `start_end` constructor parameter.
- **Manual marking** of start and end(choose any 2 given coordinates that are in path and the program does the rest (by not passing anything to `start_end`
- **(x0, y0), (x1, y1)** are accepted in `start_end` constructor for start and end respectively
- **Solving any 2-color maze** given that the maze has a clear border and a valid path (You might use my maze generator for producing a valid image)
- **Generation and saving** image of the solution in a given folder path (custom solving color, input resize and output image size).
- **Generation of animated GIF** (custom solving color and frame size) (150-200 seconds for default values, takes longer for custom values)

---

**Algorithms implemented so far:**

**1. Breadth-first search(BFS):**

- **Example 1 (Maze generated by my code - Solution - Gif)**

  [image: maze]   [image: solution]    [image: gif]
- **Example 2 (Maze generated by my code - Solution - Gif)**

  [image: maze]
  [image: solution]
  [image: gif]

---

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
import os
import cv2
import glob
import shutil
import random
import imageio
from PIL import Image
from queue import Queue
from time import perf_counter


class MazeSolver:
    """
    Solve a 2-color(wall color and path color) maze using several algorithm choices:
    - Breadth-First Search Algorithm(BFS).
    """

    def __init__(
        self,
        maze_path,
        marking_color,
        start_end=None,
        solution_size=(500, 500),
        downsize=(150, 150),
    ):
        """
        Initialize maze image, mark start and end points.
        maze_path: a string (path to maze image).
        marking_color: RGB tuple of color to use for drawing the solution path.
        solution_size: a tuple (height, width) of the solved version size.
        start_end: a tuple of x, y coordinates of maze start and x, y coordinates of maze end or
        'a' for automatic mode.
        """
        self.path = input(
            "Enter folder path to save images and GIF frames: "
        ).rstrip()
        while not os.path.exists(self.path):
            print(f"Invalid folder path {self.path}")
            self.path = input(
                "Enter folder path to save images and gifs: "
            ).rstrip()
        self.maze = Image.open(maze_path).resize(downsize)
        self.downsize = downsize
        self.height, self.width = self.maze.size
        self.maze_path = maze_path
        self.marking_color = marking_color
        if start_end == "a":
            self.initial_coordinates = []
            self._automatic_start_end()
            self.start, self.end = self.initial_coordinates
        if start_end and start_end != "a":
            self.start, self.end = start_end
        if not start_end:
            self.initial_coordinates = []
            self.titles = ["(End)", "(Start)"]
            self._set_start_end()
            self.start, self.end = self.initial_coordinates
        self.path_color = self.maze.getpixel(
            (self.start[0], self.start[1])
        )
        self.wall_color = self.maze.getpixel((0, 0))
        self.solution_name = (
            str(random.randint(10 ** 6, 10 ** 8))
            + " Maze solution"
        )
        self.output_image_size = solution_size
        self.configurations = {
            "bfs": self._breadth_first_search()
        }
        self.algorithm_names = {
            "bfs": "BREADTH-FIRST SEARCH "
        }

    def _automatic_start_end(self):
        """Determine start and end automatically"""
        start = 0
        end_rows, end_columns = (
            self.height - 1,
            self.width - 1,
        )
        border_color = self.maze.getpixel((0, 0))
        while (
            self.maze.getpixel((start, start))
            == border_color
        ):
            start += 1
        while (
            self.maze.getpixel((end_rows, end_columns))
            == border_color
        ):
            end_rows -= 1
            end_columns -= 1
        self.initial_coordinates.append((start, start))
        self.initial_coordinates.append(
            (end_rows, end_columns)
        )

    def _set_start_end(self):
        """
        Show maze image to determine coordinates.
        You will be shown the maze, click twice, first to indicate the starting point
        and second to indicate ending point and then press any key to proceed.
        """
        maze_image = cv2.imread(self.maze_path)
        resized_image = cv2.resize(
            maze_image, self.downsize
        )
        cv2.namedWindow("Maze to solve")
        cv2.setMouseCallback(
            "Maze to solve", self._get_mouse_click
        )
        cv2.imshow("Maze to solve", resized_image)
        cv2.waitKey(0)
        cv2.destroyAllWindows()
        if len(self.initial_coordinates) != 2:
            raise ValueError(
                f"Expected 2 clicks for start and end "
                f"respectively, got {len(self.initial_coordinates)}"
            )

    def _get_mouse_click(self, event, x, y, flags, param):
        """Get x, y coordinates for mouse clicks on maze image."""
        if event == cv2.EVENT_LBUTTONDOWN:
            self.initial_coordinates.append((x, y))
            print(
                f"Clicked on coordinates {x, y} {self.titles.pop()} color: {self.maze.getpixel((x, y))}"
            )

    def _get_neighbor_coordinates(self, coordinates):
        """
        Return a list of adjacent pixel coordinates that represent a path."""
        x, y = coordinates
        north = (x - 1, y)
        if north[0] < 0:
            north = None
        if (
            north
            and self.maze.getpixel(north) == self.wall_color
        ):
            north = None
        south = (x + 1, y)
        if south[0] > self.height:
            south = None
        if (
            south
            and self.maze.getpixel(south) == self.wall_color
        ):
            south = None
        east = (x, y + 1)
        if east[1] > self.width:
            east = None
        if (
            east
            and self.maze.getpixel(east) == self.wall_color
        ):
            east = None
        west = (x, y - 1)
        if west[1] < 0:
            west = None
        if (
            west
            and self.maze.getpixel(west) == self.wall_color
        ):
            west = None
        return [
            neighbor
            for neighbor in (north, south, east, west)
            if neighbor
        ]

    def _breadth_first_search(self):
        """Return path and visited pixels solved by a breadth-first search algorithm."""
        check = Queue()
        check.put([self.start])
        visited = []
        while not check.empty():
            path = check.get()
            last = path[-1]
            if last == self.end:
                return path, visited
            if last not in visited:
                neighbor_coordinates = self._get_neighbor_coordinates(
                    last
                )
                valid_coordinates = [
                    neighbor
                    for neighbor in neighbor_coordinates
                    if neighbor not in visited
                ]
                for valid_coordinate in valid_coordinates:
                    new_path = list(path)
                    new_path.append(valid_coordinate)
                    check.put(new_path)
                visited.append(last)
        raise ValueError(
            f"Too low downsize rate {self.downsize}"
        )

    def produce_path_image(self, configuration):
        """
        Draw path in maze and return solved maze picture.
        configuration: a string representing the algorithm:
        - 'bfs': solve using breadth-first search algorithm.
        """
        start_time = perf_counter()
        os.chdir(self.path)
        if configuration not in self.configurations:
            raise ValueError(
                f"Invalid configuration {configuration}"
            )
        path, visited = self.configurations[configuration]
        for coordinate in path:
            self.maze.putpixel(
                coordinate, self.marking_color
            )
        if "Solutions" not in os.listdir(self.path):
            os.mkdir("Solutions")
        os.chdir("Solutions")
        maze_name = "".join(
            [
                self.algorithm_names[configuration],
                self.solution_name,
                ".png",
            ]
        )
        resized_maze = self.maze.resize(
            self.output_image_size
        )
        resized_maze.save(maze_name)
        end_time = perf_counter()
        print(f"Time: {end_time - start_time} seconds.")
        return resized_maze

    def produce_maze_solving_visualization(
        self, configuration, frame_speed, new_size=None
    ):
        """
        Generate GIF for the solution of the maze by the selected algorithm:
        configuration: a string:
        - 'bfs': Breadth-first search algorithm.
        frame_speed: frame speed in ms
        new_size: a tuple containing new (height, width)
        """
        start_time = perf_counter()
        initial_image = Image.open(self.maze_path).resize(
            self.downsize
        )
        os.chdir(self.path)
        if configuration not in self.configurations:
            raise ValueError(
                f"Invalid configuration {configuration}"
            )
        path, visited = self.configurations[configuration]
        count = 1
        for coordinate in visited:
            self.maze.putpixel(
                coordinate, self.marking_color
            )
            if new_size:
                resized = self.maze.resize(new_size)
                resized.save(str(count) + ".png")
            else:
                self.maze.save(str(count) + ".png")
            count += 1
        if new_size:
            resized = initial_image.resize(new_size)
            resized.save(str(count) + ".png")
        else:
            initial_image.save(str(count) + ".png")
        count += 1
        for coordinate in path[::-1]:
            initial_image.putpixel(
                coordinate, self.marking_color
            )
            if new_size:
                resized = initial_image.resize(new_size)
                resized.save(str(count) + ".png")
            else:
                initial_image.save(str(count) + ".png")
            count += 1
        os.mkdir(self.solution_name)
        for file in os.listdir(self.path):
            if file.endswith(".png"):
                shutil.move(file, self.solution_name)
        os.chdir(self.solution_name)
        frames = glob.glob("*.png")
        frames.sort(key=lambda x: int(x.split(".")[0]))
        frames = [imageio.imread(frame) for frame in frames]
        imageio.mimsave(
            self.path + str(self.solution_name) + ".gif",
            frames,
            "GIF",
            duration=frame_speed,
        )
        end_time = perf_counter()
        print(f"Time: {end_time - start_time} seconds.")


if __name__ == "__main__":
    test = MazeSolver("test.png", (255, 0, 0), "a")
    test.produce_path_image("bfs").show()
```

Answer (score 3):

### Type hints

The parameters to your `MazeSolver.__init__` should get type hints, particularly for things that don't have defaults. For instance, `maze_path: str`.

### Separate input

You shouldn't be calling `input` from `__init__`. Just accept it as another parameter, and do the input and validation at a higher level.

### In-band logic

Baking `'a'` as a special condition into your `start_end` complicates your code and confuses your interface. Just have a separate boolean to trigger automatic mode.

### Presentation vs. logic

If I understand this correctly, this:

```
  while (
        self.maze.getpixel((start, start))
        == border_color
    ):
        start += 1
```

relies on an image to run the business logic. This is somewhat fragile. You're at the mercy of the resizing algorithm not to slightly change the colours of the image, particularly if there's interpolation enabled. So first, make sure interpolation is disabled during resize (I'm not sure if this is already the case). And also, you may want to have a nearest-match algorithm that finds pixel colours close to the colours your program expects for borders, etc. In the end this might look like a conversion to a two-dimensional Python list of enum values that represent business logic instead of colours.

For example,

````
from enum import Enum

class MazeValue(Enum):
   WALL = (0, 0, 0)  # e.g.
   BORDER = (20, 20, 20)

   def dist(self, colour):
      return sum((s - o)**2 for s, o in zip(self.value, colour))

   @classmethod
   def closest(cls, colour):
      return min(cls, key=lambda c: c.dist(colour))

# ...

grid = [
  [
     MazeValue.closest(self.maze.getpixel((x, y)))
     for x in self.width
  ]
  for y in self.height
]
```
````

Comment: Thanks for the feedback, if you have the time please add more details to the interpolation and nearest match algorithm part because I have no idea how to do it.

Comment: And what do you mean by 'business logic'?

Comment: Business logic basically constitutes all of the decisions that your application needs to make about your data and application behaviour.

Comment: https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Business_logic

Comment: As for the nearest-match stuff: I wrote an example. I only did a little bit of testing for the enum, and didn't feed it a real image, so your mileage may vary. You'll also want to replace the enum values, of course.